ValueError: Shapes (None, 3) and (3,) are incompatible
Has anyone successfully reproduced the code from this GitHub project：lifetime_value?
https://github.com/google/lifetime_value/tree/master
When I run "notebooks/kaggle_acquire_valued_shoppers_challenge/classification.ipynb", I'm stuck because of this error： Shapes (None, 3) and (3,) are incompatible
The error is occuring when I run this cell：
history = model.fit(
    x=x_train,
    y=y_train,
    batch_size=1024,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    verbose=2,
    callbacks=callbacks,
    validation_data=(x_eval, y_eval)).history


The error is due to a mismatch between the dimensions of the model's output and the target labels. So verify the shape of your training and evaluation labels (y_train, y_eval) and ensure that the final layer of your model is configured to output tensors with the correct shape.
